# Branching tests for error recovery, generating reports

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration

I have a project where error handling needs to be tested at every stage, so for every call it makes into another component, I'd like to return twice, once with failure and once with success.

Of course, "return twice" sounds like an ideal application of `fork()`, and that works wonderfully: my mock component calls `fork()` and returns failure in the child process and success in the parent process. System load spikes a bit, but I can verify that my component behaves like it should.

The test report generated is a bit free-form, and I haven't been able to generate a proper coverage analysis because the different child processes overwrite each others' reports. Since these problems are largely unrelated, I'm going to post these separately.

Is there a test report format that can express forking behavior like that well, and allows change analysis when test cases are added or removed?